Install Docker Desktop and build on macos-latest GitHub Actions
From searching various sources, Docker clearly doesn't run on the M1 machines. Locally I am able to run Docker Desktop. I thought I may be able to run it to build my image through GitHub Actions and push to GHCR. Building cross platform on ubuntu-latest does work, but the build times take very long and I would like to experiment building natively on ARM64. This is my workflow at the moment:
name: Build backend Docker image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Start Docker
        run: |
          brew install --cask docker
          open /Applications/Docker.app
          
          TIMEOUT=120
          INTERVAL=5
          for i in $(seq 1 $((TIMEOUT / INTERVAL))); do
           if docker info > /dev/null 2>&1; then
             echo "Docker is running."
             break
           fi
           echo "Waiting for Docker to start..."
           sleep $INTERVAL
          done
          docker info

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Cache Docker layers
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ github.sha }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-

      - name: Log in to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./backend.dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: |
            ghcr.io/me/repo:v0
            ghcr.io/me/repo:latest
          platforms: linux/arm64

      - name: Post job clean up
        if: always()
        run: |
          docker system prune -f

I keep getting the error that Docker isn't running though, am I doing something wrong?
